# How to call two function from same onclick in Keystone?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I am using keystonejs in my project and I am try to call two function from same onclick.I have tried below code but doesn't work.

```
    onclick="eventa(); eventb();"
```

I have also tried to make event function having both above function but doesn't work. Please suggest if there is any other method in keystone.

Comment: You **onclick** event definition seems correct, I speculate your *eventa* and *eventb* functions are not correctly performing the tasks they are meant to. Please paste more of your HTML and the script which contains your two functions so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you call them both from another function?, or let the first one to call the other?